Why is Antonio the changeling?
Towards the end of The Changeling (1653), after De Flores stabs Beatrice-Joanna and then reveals that the two of them have been murderers and lovers, the dying Beatrice-Joanna says to her shocked father:

O come not near me, sir, I shall defile you:
I am that of your blood was taken from you
For your better health.
Middleton, Thomas, and William Rowley. The Changeling. 1653. Thomas Middleton: Five Plays. Eds. Bryan Loughrey and Neil Taylor. London: Penguin Classics, 1988: 345–421. V.3.149–151, p. 419.

Isolated from the metaphor of bloodletting, the line I am that of your blood was taken from you suggests that the original Beatrice-Joanna was kidnapped by magic, and an evil substitute (a changeling) left in her place. One can see either Beatrice-Joanna's falling in love with Alsemero despite her engagement to Alonzo, or her thralldom to De Flores after he kills Alonzo at her behest, as the moment of evil enchantment when a corrupt Beatrice-Joanna replaces the hitherto virtuous one.
Yet the cast of characters (p. 346) lists an entirely different character as "the changeling": Antonio, a courtier who pretends to be mentally deficient so as to woo Isabella, the wife of the jealous keeper of the lunatic asylum. The parallels between the Isabella sub-plot and the main narrative of Beatrice-Joanna are readily discernable. But I do not understand what makes Antonio the changeling. Why is this relatively minor character supposedly the titular changeling? It cannot be simply that he pretends to be someone else, because that applies equally to Franciscus, who is described in the cast of characters as "the counterfeit madman." So what about Antonio's role is important enough to name the play after him or vice-versa?

The meaning of "changeling" of Shakespeare are most familiar with is used in the following lines from A Midsummer Night's Dream, Act 2, scene 1:

For Oberon is passing fell and wrath,
Because that she as her attendant hath
A lovely boy, stolen from an Indian king.
She never had so sweet a changeling,

In his edition of the play in the New Penguin Shakespeare, Stanley Wells glosses "changeling" as follows:

usually a child left by fairies in exchange for one stolen, but here, the stolen child.

The first three meanings in Wiktionary are the following:


(European folklore, also figurative) In pre-modern European folklore: an infant of a magical creature that was secretly exchanged for a human infant. In British, Irish and Scandinavian mythology the exchanged infants were thought to be those of fairies, sprites or trolls; in other places, they were ascribed to demons, devils, or witches.
(by extension) A person or object (especially when regarded as inferior) secretly exchanged for something else.
(by extension, informal, rare) An infant secretly exchanged with another infant deliberately or by mistake; a swapling.


However, Richard Dutton explains in his edition of Women Beware Women and Other Plays that changeling here means "idiot" (page 384). In the introduction, Dutton writes (page xxviii),

The 'changeling' of the title is probably Antonio, who substitutes himself in the role of a fool; (…).

However,

Beatrice-Joanna is another 'changeling', fickle in her sexual preferences, choosing Alonzo and then almost immediately preferring Alsemero, but finally obsessed with Deflores, to whom she once had a pathological aversion.

Sources

Middleton, Thomas. Women Beware Women and Other Plays. Edited by Richard Dutton. Oxford University Press, 1999.
Shakespeare, William. A Midsummer Night's Dream. Edited by Stanley Wells. The New Penguin Shakespeare. Penguin, 1995.


Thanks. I'm not sure how this answers the question? I wasn't asking what "changeling" meant; I was asking "what about Antonio's role is important enough to name the play after him or vice-versa?", and that question remains. Can you clarify?
